# Find the angle ADE of the given triangle.

Tags: geometry

**Given** : 

Angle ABE = 50, Angle DAC = 20, Angle BAD = 60, Angle ACB = 20 and Side CD = Side DA.
Unit of angle values given is **degree**.

**Find** : Angle ADE.

[image]

I'm stuck and I need help here.

Comment: There are not enough equations to decipher the value of $x$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQc-54hQ8kw

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: you're wrong: the triangle (up to scaling) is fixed, hence it is the amplitude of $x$, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Wow I thought this was an ordinary problem. Ok, this is something interesting.

Answer (score 4):

This problem keeps reappearing. Probably this is the $n$-th duplicate.

The information $CD=DA$ is redundant. It follows from $\angle \, DAC = \angle \, ACB = 20^{\circ}$.

**Hints:**

What is $\angle \, AEB$? Then focus on triangle $ABE$. Anything special about it? Then choose point $F$ on $CA$ so that $\angle \, ABF = 60^{\circ}$. Let $G$ be the intersection point of $AD$ and $BF$. What can you say about triangles 
$$ABG, \,\, AEG, \,\, EFG, \,\, DFG?$$ What is special about them? Now, is the role of $ED$ clearer? Finally, how much is $\angle \, ADE \,$?